# Scraping links from more than one URL

Tags: python, url, scraperwiki

I'm using ScraperWiki to pull in links from the london-gazette.co.uk site. How would I edit the code so that I can paste in a number of separate search URLs at the bottom which are all collated into the same datastore?

At the moment I can just paste in the new URL, hit run, and the new data is added on to the back of the old data, but I was wondering if there's a way to speed things up and get the scraper to work on several URLs at once? I would be changing the 'notice code' part of the URLs: `issues/2013-01-15;2013-01-15/all=NoticeCode%3a2441/start=1`

Sorry - new to Stack Overflow and my coding knowledge is pretty much non existent, but the code is here: https://scraperwiki.com/scrapers/links_1/edit/

Comment: Is my answer what you wanted or are you looking for something else?

Comment: Sorry, had somehow turned email notifications off. Thanks, but it didn't work. It worked for your example scraper, but when I tried to adapt it to change the notice code section of the URL I got nowhere.

Comment: Can you give an example list of URLs you want to scrape?

Comment: Sure, the start of every URL is http://www.london-gazette.co.uk/

Then I'd be looking at scraping URLs that vary by notice code and date, like such: issues/2013-01-15;2013-01-15/all=NoticeCode%3a2441/start=1   /   issues/2013-01-15;2013-01-15/all=NoticeCode%3a2453/start=1   /  issues/2013-01-15;2013-01-15/all=NoticeCode%3a2462/start=1    /  issues/2012-02-10;2013-02-20/all=NoticeCode%3a2441/start=1

Comment: These URLs work well with the code from my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scraper you linked to seems to be empty, but I had a look at the original scraper by Rebecca Ratcliffe. If yours is the same, you only have to put your URLs into a list and loop through them with a for-loop:

```
urls = ['/issues/2013-01-15;2013-01-15/all=NoticeCode%3a2441/start=1', 
'/issues /2013-01-15;2013-01-15/all=NoticeCode%3a2453/start=1',
'/issues/2013-01-15;2013-01-15/all=NoticeCode%3a2462/start=1', 
'/issues/2012-02-10;2013-02-20/all=NoticeCode%3a2441/start=1']

base_url = 'http://www.london-gazette.co.uk'
for u in urls:
    starting_url = urlparse.urljoin(base_url, u)
    scrape_and_look_for_next_link(starting_url)
```

Just have a look at [this scraper](https://scraperwiki.com/scrapers/aoa6_2/) that I copied and adapted accordingly.